# Javascript - Adding images to objects via object literal notation

Tags: javascript, image

I have been trying to add an image to several different objects via object literal notation.

I couldn't get it to work and was wondering if anyone had any insight on this.

```
var hotelRooms = [
  {
   hotel: 'Hotel Hawaii',
   price: '$350 / Night',
   size: '400 Square Feet',
   img: 'images/image.src', // What I have tried.
   image: 'images/image.src' // What I have tried.
  },
  {
   hotel: 'Downtown Hawaii',
   price: '$450 / Night',
   size: '300 Square Feet',
   img: 'images/image.src', // What I have tried.
   image: 'images/image.src' // What I have tried.
 }
];
```

Comment: Can you show example of your purpose?

Comment: Please define an image in a JS object. An URL to an image? A Blob object? HTMLImageElement? Or some of the several other possibilities?

Comment: I have updated my code

Comment: Please also define "I couldn't get it to work". How are you using this data object? Do you want to store an image or show it on a page or something else?

Comment: Your code still doesn't provide as much information as you seem to think it does. What do you mean by "what I have tried"? What are you expecting it to do? What is it not doing? What is `images/image.src`? .src is not any image file format that I'm not aware of, is it supposed to be a file on your server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can either add URLs:

```
var hotelRooms = [
    {
        hotel: 'Hotel Hawaii',
        price: '$350 / Night',
        size: '400 Square Feet',
        imgUrl: 'https://www.example.com/images/img123.jpg'
    }
];
```

or filenames as strings:

```
var hotelRooms = [
    {
        hotel: 'Hotel Hawaii',
        price: '$350 / Night',
        size: '400 Square Feet',
        imgFile: 'img123.jpg'
    }
];
```

or construct them from some kind of ID:

```
var hotelRooms = [
    {
        hotel: 'Hotel Hawaii',
        price: '$350 / Night',
        size: '400 Square Feet',
        id: 123
    }
];
```

by building a URL like:

```
"https://www.example.com/images/img" + hotelRooms[0].id + ".jpg";
```

When you have an URL like that - either stored directly as an object property or constructed from parts - you can use it in a template or add it to a `src` attribute of an `<img>` tag.

It's hard to say anything more because you wasn't very specific in the question on what exactly do you want to do with those images so I can only do my best in guessing.

Keep in mind that what you have here is not valid JSON. If you need to construct JSON it would be something like this:

```
[
    {
        "hotel": "Hotel Hawaii",
        "price": "$350 / Night",
        "size": "400 Square Feet",
        "id": 123
    }
]
```

with double-quoted strings and object keys.

You didn't say anything about JSON per se but people often try to process data like this as JSON and it doesn't work without properly quoted keys - those in JS it's ok to have unquoted keys (that are not reserved words) and single-quoted strings.